# Laptop lost power while installing dual boot Ubuntu gnome along side Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10

My laptop wasn't plugged in while I was part way through installing Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 from a live USB alongside Windows 10 UEFI. My laptop powered down during the part where it was actually installing (just before this step I had chosen English, created a password to bypass Secure Boot, selected how much GB for Ubuntu partition, chosen to install extras, etc.)

After this happened I thought to try to install Ubuntu Gnome again but when I got to the step where I had to choose how much space to give to Ubuntu, I had only like 20GB. At that point I realized that the 250GB partition (I had chosen during the first install attempt) was now inaccessible.

At this point I booted back to Win10 and used EaseUS Partition Master to clean my C: NTFS 951GB partition of unnecessary files thinking this might help. As far as I can see now I have 334GB of space on my C: partition *(screen shots below)*

I then ran `chkdsk /scan` and any problem that was found was fixed online automatically and in the end it printed out:

```
 935423999 KB total disk space.
     506764964 KB in 525982 files.
        385536 KB in 90914 indexes.
             0 KB in bad sectors.
       1071903 KB in use by the system.
         65536 KB occupied by the log file.
     427201596 KB available on disk.

          4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
     233855999 total allocation units on disk.
     106800399 allocation units available on disk.
```

I'm no expert but it looks as if those are clean results.

So how can I get back that 250GB partition and dual-boot install Ubunutu Gnome 17.04 from Live USB again?

*Screenshot of EaseUS*
[image]

*Screenshot of Windows Disk Manager*
[image]

### UPDATE 1:

I'm not able to shrink my C: windows8_OS partition via Disk Manager even though it says I have 328GB of free space. I can't even shrink it by 1MB! So it appears something is really off.

*Screenshot of C: properties*

[image]

*Screenshot of Disk Manager's Shrink UI dialogue pop-up*

[image]

But wait. I've gone into EaseUS and tried to see if I could resize C: and apparently I can. (View GIF below) This is totally inconsistent with what Disk Manager is allowing me to do.

[image]

Also I ran a surface test in EaseUS and got no bad sectors.

[image]

### UPDATE 2:

I booted into Ubunutu via the Live USB, started up GParted and was also unable to resize the Windows8_OS 892 GB NTFS partition. I also saw a warning message that said:

> Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some
>   operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software
>   package. The following list of software packages is required for ntfs
>   file system support: ntfsprogs / ntfs-3g.

Here are screenshots of what I saw in GParted 
[image: gparted main window]
[image: warning message]
[image: resize window]

### UPDATE 3:

Ok so I tried to resize C: with EaseUS Partition Master and it said there was an error with C:, to fix it and try again. Here is a link to the screenshot I took at Imgur [EaseUS error screen after trying to resize C:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gEr.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure where you managed to select the 250GB in the first place. Your Windows Disk Manager screen shot shows a disk fully allocated to Windows. The proper steps to take is to shrink your C: partition by at least 60GB. The WDM will then show that as Unallocated or Free. Only then you can install Ubuntu in there. As an alternative you can decide to install VirtualBox or VMPlayer in Windows and install Ubuntu as a virtual machine. That way you can have both OS's online simultaneously.

Comment: Using Windows disk manager is not recommended. Because it may or may not support Linux partition formats (`lvm` for example). Boot into Ubuntu 17.04 live media and open GParted and try again.

Comment: @WillemK I selected 250GB the first time I was installing Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 as a dual boot. I was presented with a slider to allocate the amount of space for Ubuntu. Previous to doing that I shrank my C: drive using Disk Manager in Windows 10.

Comment: @reversiblean Understood but what exactly should I do when I open Gparted while running Live USB? Shrink the Windows8_OS volume?

Comment: @max you'd simply delete (or format) whatever not necessary and complete with the Ubuntu installation. Or post a screenshot of your GParted so we could have a look.

Comment: @max: you must shrink C: from within Windows, just as you described in your previous comment. If you shrink it in gparted, the next time you boot Windows it probably ruin your partition again.

Comment: @WillemK I've tried to shrink C: via Disk Manager's shrink UI but it shows me that I have no room to shrink it. However the main DM window shows that I have 328GB of free space. I updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: @WillemK weird. apparently EaseUS is allowing me to shrink C:. I updated my "update" with a GIF showing this. Now I'm totally unsure what to do.

Comment: @max: Umm.. odd. How about shrinking it by 60GB with EasyUS and reboot. If boot is successful, does Disk Manager show the 60GB as free space? If so, boot your Ubuntu Live USB and open `gparted` to see if that too shows the 60GB unallocated space. If it does, then I don´t see any objection to install Ubuntu in the unallocated space. But I have another suggestion for you to consider...

Comment: ... and that is install VMware Player in Windows and install Ubuntu as a virtual machine in VMPlayer. Pro´s: you don´t have to mess around with partitions. You can have Windows and Ubuntu running simultaneously. You can have multiple Ubuntu VM´s. Con´s: every vm uses RAM memory and CPU, your machine should have enough to keep Windows running ok.

Comment: @WillemK I tried Virtual Box before this and it was running super slow so I gave up. I will try what you said before about shrinking with EasyUS, rebooting, running WDM to see if it worked and if it worked going ahead with Ubuntu install. Thanks and I'll report back.

Comment: @reversiblean hey I posted the screenshots of GParted in the question under UPDATE 2. let me know if you'll need to see anything else. thanks.

Comment: Echoing WillemK I STRONGLY advise against operating on your Windows partition with gparted. In my painful experience that is a good way to break your Windows system.  Operate on Windows partitions only with Windows tools.  I have had good results with the Easus tools. Once you have made room, boot into Live USB "try" option and set up LInux partitions with gparted. Then install with Something Else option.

Comment: @OrganicMarble in my experience it won't break unless you do something stupid like shrinking bootloader

Comment: @OrganicMarble I tried to resize with EaseUS but I hit an error called message 357 stating that it found an error on my C: drive and to fix it. So I contacted EaseUS with this and will report back. I added a screenshot in Update 3

Comment: @WillemK I tried what you said but EaseUS failed. Hit an error. I added update 3 explaining this.

Comment: I have zero experience with Easeus, so I cannot comment on it. I always use Minitool Partition Magic (https://www.partitionwizard.com) for resizing Windows disks and it never failed me yet. Was thinking... when you are in Windows, do a 'defrag' of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended that you use Windows Disk Manager for partitioning. Because it can results in a dynamic partition table. And dynamic partitions are not supported by non-windows operating systems.

In your case you should first install `ntfs-3g` package, for your system to be able to read NTFS file systems.

```
$ apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then simply try to resize the partition. And it should work.

**NOTE**: and make sure to shrink from right.